# Sails query by joined table

Tags: orm, sails.js

In sails I need function to get rows by referenced table. Something like

```
Child.find({ parent.age: 30 })
```

or in SQL language

```
SELECT child.* FROM child JOIN parent ON child.parent_id = parent.id WHERE parent.age = 30
```

So far I have written uggly function which does the work in 3 steps:

```
    get_children_in_celebration: function(req, res) {

      // 1. Get parend ids
      Parent.find({ select: ['id'], age: 30}).exec(function(err_parents, res_parents) {

        // 2. Collect them to array suitable for next query
        var parent_ids = [];
        for(var i = 0; i < res_parents.length; i++) {
          parent_ids[i] = res_parents[i].id;
        }

        // Get their children
        Child.find({ parent_id: parent_ids }).exec(function(err_children, res_children) {
          return res.json(res_children);
        });
      });
    },
```

The first query returns ~5000 parents and therefore together it means heavy load for db. Does sails offer any nicer solution?

Comment: Unfortunately no...

Answer (score 1):

No, Sails does not support filtering on associated table. I had the similar issue, had used raw queries for the same.

```
Model.query("select * from table", function (error, response) {})
```